# Sublime Highlight when select characters

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm using **VSCode**, and it has a nice thing to match characteres *(without <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>)*. Same as the image below.
Is there any plugin to **sublimeText** to do the same thing?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Is not exactly the same but... you can highlight all matchings with currently selected text by clicking Alt-F3 (or Find -> Quick find all)

Comment: Yeah, i know that... but VSCode makes this action pretty much easier

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was curious about this, so I've done some research:

There's a SublimeText plugin that does **exactly** what your are looking for:

[SublimeText/WordHighlight](https://github.com/SublimeText/WordHighlight) can be easily installed via `Preferences` -> `Package Control` -> `Install package` -> *WordHighLight* (or the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> -> Type *Install package* -> Type *WordHighLight*).

Once installed, when a word is selected, all matching words in the document are highlighted:

[image]

I've tested it successfully in SublimeText 3.

Don't forget to add

```
{
    "highlight_non_word_characters": true,
}
```

...to your `Preferences` -> `Package settings` -> `WordHighLight` -> `Settings - User` in case you want to highlight partial words, as the sample you provided. Otherwise, only complete words are highlighted.

Comment: Veeeery nice!! Thanks a lot man, i have been searching for this for long!